# Android Private Libraries disappear after add a lib

Tags: android

Before add a new lib to my project, I still got Android Private Libraries.
After I add a lib, all of sudden the Android Private Libraries disappear from my project.

What's problem I got? Is the lib I add to project forbid Android Private Libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I've sovled this issue, there's a conflict of libraries, my app's android-support-v4 version is different from the lib's android-support-v4 version. Check the console, it can show you the error